# how to convert index into C(N,K), K=2

Tags: combinatorics

i am trying to enumerate pairs in random order,
by generating index $J$ and converting it into pair parts

$\binom{N}{2}$ have two items - let's say $x$ and $y$

$N, x, y, J \in \{0,1,2,..\}$

$0 <= x < y < N$

$0 <= J < T, T = \frac{N (N-1)}{2}$

how to find $x$ and $y$ if $N$ and $J$ are known ?

"need an explicit bijection from $\{0,\ldots, \binom{N}{2}-1\}$ to the collection of 2-subsets of $\{0,1,\ldots,N-1\}$." as Anthony Quas said

others says there are [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2011-February/006356.html

Comment: The computer science answer is binary search.

Comment: it looks like a simple case (not a generic one), that is why i hope that it can be solved somehow with arithmetic operations and rounding

Answer (score 0):

```
public class IndexToPairMapper
{
    public readonly int N;
    public IndexToPairMapper (int N)
    {
        this.N = N;
    }
    public Point GetPairByIndex(long index)
    {
        int row = (int)Math.Floor ( (Math.Sqrt (index * 8 + 1) - 1) / 2);
        long subTotal = row * (row + 1) / 2;
        Point cp;
        cp.X = (int)(index - subTotal);
        cp.Y = Negate(row - cp.X);
        return cp;
    }
    public long GetIndexByPair(Point cp)
    {
        int negB = Negate(cp.Y);
        int row = cp.X + negB;
        long subTotal = row * (row + 1) / 2;
        long index = subTotal + cp.X;
        return index;
    }
    int Negate (int i)
    {
        return (N - 1) - i;
    }
}
```